# Not sure why getting Duplicate method onClick(View)

Tags: android

I've got one activity
here is what I am trying do. When app starts an image is displayed. When the image is clicked the next image is displayed. 
I've got it all setup with main.xml and imageview.
The app builds and runs and displays the first image no problem.
Now trying to setup onclick for the image so the next image will be displayed. I've added android:onClick="onClick" to the image vew in main.xml.
I am using (this) for setOnClickListner and I implemented View.onClickListener for the class but the switch case I setup I get duplicate method for onClick(View v) and I'm not sure why.

Also trying to figure out the findViewById I think the way I have it image1 will always be displayed.

getting error on line public void onClick(View v) that it is a duplicate method.

Here is the code I have. Thanks for any assistance on this.

main.xml is a linear layout not sure  that matters.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/bear"        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/bear_n"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />
```

This is the .java file.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class VTFCActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

ImageView image;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    image1.setOnClickListener(this);
    image2.setOnClickListener(this);

}
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){

    case R.id.imageView1:
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bear);
        break;
    case R.id.imageView2:
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bear_n);
        break;          
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your error logcat.

Comment: You must accept one of answers among several if any solves your issue there are many which concern the solution

Comment: @DipakKeshariya there will be no log cat error every thing is clear by these two code from xml and java one enough to clarify the solution

Answer (score 1):

when you use

```
image1.setOnClickListener(this);
image2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

you have to override the default onClick() Method in th Android API:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
```

also setting in xml `android:onClick="onClick"`

will let you handle clik event from your custom onClick Method

and that's way an exception is throwed to you: telling that you have a duplicate method!!

so you have two choices:

1. remove `android:onClick="onClick"`: and that's what i would do
2. remove `image1.setOnClickListener(this);`  `image2.setOnClickListener(this);` and handle clicks on your way on the custom onClick() method

Answer (score 0):

> Now trying to setup onclick for the image so the next image will be
>   displayed. I've added android:onClick="onClick" to the image vew in
>   main.xml.

If you have added android:onClick="onClick" to the both image views in main.xml
You should remove `image1.setOnClickListener(this);` and `image2.setOnClickListener(this);`
from code since you have already specified it in main xml.

Comment: yes. Either `android:onClick="onClick"` or `image1.setOnClickListener(this);` , not both...

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            final Dialog dl = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

            dl.setContentView(R.layout.cdialog);

            dl.setTitle("Title");


            TextView txt = (TextView) dl.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            txt.setText("Hi \n How are you \n" +
                    "Where were you \n Good to see you");

            Button btn = (Button) dl.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    dl.dismiss();

                }
            });
            dl.show();
        }
    });
}
}
```